# Flexslider 2.2 Carousel slides don't stay synced after animationLoop

Tags: slider, slideshow, carousel, flexslider

Anybody have any suggestions for me?

I have a Flexslider 2.2 Slider and Carousel on my page that scrolls through 8 images.  After the eighth, I have the animationLoop set to True to force it to keep repeating the eight.  The problem is that after the Slider and Carousel has navigated all eight, the Slider goes back to Slide 1, but the Carousel is stuck until the Slider gets to the second image.  Then the Carousel syncs back up and works for 2-8 slides.

This can be seen at: http://www.raggeddaisy.com

Here is my Head:

```
<head>
    <title> Ragged Daisy - Handcrafted Home Decor </title>

    <!-- jQuery -->

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.7.min.js">\x3C/script>')</script>

    <!-- Syntax Highlighter -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/shCore.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/shBrushXml.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/shBrushJScript.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/modernizr.js"></script>

    <!-- Optional FlexSlider Additions -->
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.easing.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>

      <!-- FlexSlider -->
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/flexslider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

</head>
```

Here is my body:

```
<body>
    <div id="bodyHeader" class="bodyHeader">
        HOME
    </div>
    <div id="bodyText" class="bodyText">
        Welcome to Ragged Daisy! We are a family-owned operation dedicated to designing quality, handcrafted home decor. All of our pieces are uniquely created from scratch using quality materials designed to last. We take pride in our craftsmanship from start to finish, as each piece is expertly made with exceptional precision and care. 
        <br> <br> 
        Our collections are all hand finished to produce a beautiful depth of color and texture. Whether you are looking to capture the warmth and playful charm of softly worn, authentic pieces, or emphasize glamour and elegance with chic, sophisticated pieces, our collection is designed to add flare and functionality in all the spaces you live, work and play.
        <br> <br> 
        Ragged Daisy is located just a few miles north of Minneapolis, Minnesota, USA. We ship product locally and nationally. We are honored when you choose us to create a special handcrafted piece for your space. Our collections are evolving and growing so please check back with us!

    </div>

<!-- Beginning of Slideshow -->

    <div id="main" role="main">
      <section class="slider">
        <div id="slider" class="flexslider">
          <ul class="slides">
            <li>
                <img src="~/Images/Products/WoodenSign/PNG/1-AMORE.PNG" alt="Ragged Daisy - Decorative AMORE Wooden Sign" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="~/Images/Products/MagneticBoard/PNG/1-SmallProvincial_tanswirls.png" alt ="Ragged Daisy - Magnetic Board with Provincial Stain and Tan Swirls Fabric"/>
            </li>
             <li>
                <img src="~/Images/Products/Bench/PNG/1-BenchFullShot.png" alt ="Ragged Daisy - Stylish Wooden Pallet Bench"/>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="~/Images/Products/Bench/PNG/2-CabinRight.png" alt="Ragged Daisy - Stylish Wooden Pallet Bench Provincial Stain" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="~/Images/Products/MagneticBoard/PNG/2-vintagewhiteframe_mexicanfiesta_fullshot.png" alt ="Ragged Daisy - Magnetic Board with Vintage White Frame and Mexican Fiesta Fabric"/>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="~/Images/Products/MagneticBoard/PNG/3-vintagewhiteframe_tanswirls_fullshot.png" alt ="Ragged Daisy - Magnetic Board with Vintage White Frame and Tan Swirls Fabric"/>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="~/Images/Products/MagneticBoard/PNG/4-TurquoiseBoard_outsideshot.png" alt ="Ragged Daisy - Magnetic Board with Turquoise Weathered Finish with Metal and Hooks"/>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="~/Images/Products/WoodenSign/PNG/3-LOVE.PNG" alt="Ragged Daisy - Decorative LOVE Wooden Sign"/>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="carousel" class="flexslider">
          <ul class="slides">
            <li>
                <img src="~/Images/Products/WoodenSign/PNG/1-AMORE.PNG" alt="Ragged Daisy - Decorative AMORE Wooden Sign" />
                </li>
            <li>
                <img src="~/Images/Products/MagneticBoard/PNG/1-SmallProvincial_tanswirls.png" alt ="Ragged Daisy - Magnetic Board with Provincial Stain and Tan Swirls Fabric"/>
            </li>
             <li>
                <img src="~/Images/Products/Bench/PNG/1-BenchFullShot.png" alt ="Ragged Daisy - Stylish Wooden Pallet Bench"/>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="~/Images/Products/Bench/PNG/2-CabinRight.png" alt="Ragged Daisy - Stylish Wooden Pallet Bench Provincial Stain" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="~/Images/Products/MagneticBoard/PNG/2-vintagewhiteframe_mexicanfiesta_fullshot.png" alt ="Ragged Daisy - Magnetic Board with Vintage White Frame and Mexican Fiesta Fabric"/>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="~/Images/Products/MagneticBoard/PNG/3-vintagewhiteframe_tanswirls_fullshot.png" alt ="Ragged Daisy - Magnetic Board with Vintage White Frame and Tan Swirls Fabric"/>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="~/Images/Products/MagneticBoard/PNG/4-TurquoiseBoard_outsideshot.png" alt ="Ragged Daisy - Magnetic Board with Turquoise Weathered Finish with Metal and Hooks"/>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="~/Images/Products/WoodenSign/PNG/3-LOVE.PNG" alt="Ragged Daisy - Decorative LOVE Wooden Sign"/>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </section>
  </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
      SyntaxHighlighter.all();
    });
    $(window).load(function(){
      $('#carousel').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        controlNav: false,
        animationLoop: true,
        slideshow: false,
        itemWidth: 105,
        itemMargin: 0,
        asNavFor: '#slider'
      });

      $('#slider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        controlNav: false,
        animationLoop: true,
        slideshow: true,
        sync: "#carousel",
        start: function(slider){
          $('body').removeClass('loading');
        }
      });
    });
  </script>

</body>
```

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas for me?

Answer (score 2):

Had same problem and made a workaround.

```
 $('#slider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        controlNav: false,
        animationLoop: true,
        slideshow: true,
        sync: "#carousel",
        start: function(slider){
          $('body').removeClass('loading');
        }
        before: function(slider){         
            if(slider.currentSlide == 0 && slider.direction == "prev"){ //start
                var carousel = $(slider.vars.sync).data('flexslider');
                carousel.flexAnimate(carousel.last);

            }else if( slider.currentSlide == slider.last && slider.direction == "next"){ // end
                var carousel = $(slider.vars.sync).data('flexslider');
                carousel.flexAnimate(0);
            }
        }
      });
```